# Set GETDATE() when an UPDATE WHERE is dynamic

Tags: logging, sql-server-2008-r2, gettime

I have a table named `Stored_Procedure_Logging` where I store the logging of my stored procedure.

```
SPD_name       Start_process             End_process
SPD_MySpd      2015-04-09 18:06:50       NULL
```

The first script will insert the Start time by this way :

```
INSERT INTO Stored_Procedure_Logging (Start_process,SPD_name) 
VALUES (GETDATE(),OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID))
```

And when the SDP finish its run I must update the previous inserted record with the End time with this below script but it does not working !!

I find a NULL value in the second column (End_process)

```
UPDATE  Stored_Procedure_Logging 
SET End_process = GETDATE() 
WHERE SPD_name =OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

`OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` is to get the current SPD

Can you help me please ??

Comment: What RDBMS are you using. Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Are you sure `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` is returning the correct value when you run the second query?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, in fact the issue is with the second query ..
But It works when I try with this (without OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) ) :

UPDATE  Stored_Procedure_Logging 
SET End_process = GETDATE() 
WHERE SPD_name ='SPD_MySpd'

Comment: Can you provide a more real-world example? Meaning are you doing: INSERT _realwork_ UPDATE all in the same sproc?

Comment: Yes it's the case my spd is coded as below :

CREATE  PROCEDURE  SPD_MySpd

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Stored_Procedure_Logging (Start_process,SPD_name) 
VALUES (GETDATE(),OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID))

.
.
.

UPDATE  Stored_Procedure_Logging 
SET End_process = GETDATE() 
WHERE SPD_name =OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)

END

Answer (score 0):

How ever there is a wrong in update query's where clause. it is may not syntax error but   may be OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) value is null.

check OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) value. 
may be after processing    OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) return different value

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, in fact the issue is with the second query ..
But It works when I try with this (without OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) ) :

UPDATE  Stored_Procedure_Logging 
SET End_process = GETDATE() 
WHERE SPD_name ='SPD_MySpd'

Comment: That makes it pretty clear that the problem is that `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` is not returning the name you want. What does `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) FROM dual` return?

Comment: in sql server there is no table call dual (Like oracle). I m not familier with object_name. but you can write like this  WHERE SPD_name IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID))

Comment: When i write SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)  I get the name my sproc..

OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)  returns 'nvarchar' but SPD_name is a 'varchar'  , is that may be the problem ?